# How to Resolve this Xamarin MAUI bug

Tags: debugging, xamarin, maui

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is packages\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.3.31.2\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.targets.    SampleProject   C:\Users\world\source\repos\SampleProject\SampeTest.csproj    257 **your text**

I have tried to restore nuget packages.but it not gives access

Comment: What does Nuget say when you try to install that package?

Comment: This Project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

Comment: Nuget should request them from the remote repository.  Have you checked your nuget sources?  What does the complete nuget log show when you attempt to restore packages?

Comment: Double and Triple check your NuGet packages, and sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `package restore behavior` to allow NuGet to download missing packages.

You can check this article about [Restore by using the NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore?source=recommendations#restore-by-using-the-nuget-cli). The NuGet CLI restore command downloads and installs any missing packages.